# Why is "too" used in this negative sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, negation

This is a news headline on CNN.

> I was targeted during Nixon's administration. Trump shouldn't make an enemies list, **too**.

Why do they use "too", instead of " either" here? Isn't it a grammatical error?

[image]

Comment: And don't assume journalists write well either.

Comment: This headline is a quote, and it should be just like the author said it.

Comment: Please note that back in March [you were asked not to post images without transcriptions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159130/what-does-unplugged-mean-or-imply-in-this-headline#comment320217_159130).  Please re-read the comment, and please don't do this in future questions.

Comment: @bartolo-otrit [some] journalists are notoriously sloppy about quoting people accurately.

Answer (score 2):

It is not

> Trump shouldn't make a shopping list and an enemies list too.

but rather:

> Trump should not make an enemies list *as Nixon did*.
>
> Nixon made an enemies list. An enemies list should not be made by Trump, too  [i.e. in addition to Nixon, or adding his own name to the names of presidents who made an enemies list].

This is a perfectly idiomatic colloquial English statement.  The placement of **too** can create ambiguities, but context usually clears them up.

The statement means "Trump, now, should not be doing the same thing himself".

Suppose someone asked the same question yesterday, and now today you're asking it. One could say:

> This question was asked and answered yesterday. You shouldn't be asking the question **too**.

P.S. **either** instead of **too** there would say that neither Nixon nor Trump should have engaged in the practice.  **too** does not *entail* anything untoward about Nixon, just as in my last example with **too** there's no critique of the person who asked the question yesterday.

Comment: I'm not convinced. There's a difference between *We're going, but you shouldn't go **too*** and *We're **not** going, and you shouldn't go **either***. But OP's text doesn't give the full context anyway, so I don't know which of those usages applies to the cited text.

Comment: +1.  Knowing that Nixon (quite famously) had an enemies list is enough context to understand the headline, I think.

Comment: @snailboat: The question title mentioned  "in this negative sentence" so I figured the OP might be questioning the semantics of "not .... also".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I cannot convince you that it's perfectly idiomatic (at least in AmE) except by finding attestations of the (colloquial) pattern.